# chatbot transfer to live agent is showing me no agents are available

Tags: community, liveagent, einstein, omnichannel

I've created a basic chat bot in salesforce and have a transfer to Agent option in it. Here my bot is working fine for all the conversation. but when I click on `Transfer to Agent` it gives me a message as `no Agents are available`.

I've created another live agent (the regular one, not a bot), and when I start it, it shows me the option to `chat with expert`, and on my console, I get a popup saying that there is a chat request.

Here are the screenshots of the same.

[image: Error on Live Agent transfer]

[image: Request for a live agent support (not going through bot)]

[image: Request received at the Console]

please let me know on where I might be going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue: what you need to do is create 2 queues. The bot and agents should be in one queue (this will be used for the handoff from bot to agent. The other queue is only for agents and what your code should query for agent availability. Salesforce has samples online and recommended this approach to us (which worked).

Comment: Can you provide a link for this behaviour?